# How do I get rid of the white space between my adsense ad and home and next post buttons?

Tags: css, layout, whitespace

I want to tighten up or get rid of the white space between my google ad and my home and older posts buttons any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Use this snippet -

```
.footer-inner {
    padding-top: 0;
}
.region-inner.main-inner {
    padding-bottom: 0;
}

div#blog-pager {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Add this too and see what happens.

Comment: im confused as what to type in